# How to force SIM to use WiFi calling using the internet provided by eSIM?

Tags: iphone, esim

For internet, I have eSIM, no WiFi.

For calls/texts, I have SIM, which has no internet.

I want SIM to use WiFi calling using the internet eSIM provides.

I tried selecting networks manually to choose something that doesn't get signal, but this usually doesn't work because all options get signal.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: This is quite unclear.  You can't *force* eSIM to use WiFi.  "You want the SIM to use to use the internet that eSIM provides." A SIM is an access token, not something that creates/destroys networks

Answer (score 1):

I am under the assumption that the person who is asking this question is traveling internationally and is looking to avoid roaming charges by their home carrier. The method I am about to describe requires the iPhone user to be present in their home carrier's service area (do this before your trip). The instructions are:

Go to Settings, click on Cellular

[image: Settings page]

You need to turn on Wi-Fi calling. Hopefully, you get to a page similar to this:

[image: Cellular settings].

Once you do, click on "Network Selection".

It brings you to this:

[image: Network selection screen].

Uncheck "Automatic" and select your own carrier's name, like this:[image: manual selection].

Once all these steps are done, and you add your eSIM with data and configure it properly to use data in your destination, you will be able to force the home carrier to " using cellular data". As long as you adhere to your home carrier's plan rules (especially when it comes to calling international numbers), you will only be charged the regular plan fee you have been paying while at home.

Comment: That's what I have been doing. I choose a provider that has no signal to force the sim to use esim's internet. But sometimes I need to get a signal in regular way (so I choose automatic), then I can't switch back to a provider that has no signal in some countries because all of them get signal. I guess there's no solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

If Wi-Fi Calling over Cellular Data works in some cases, but you want it to work all the time, unfortunately you're probably out of luck.

The phone will always try to use the primary SIM directly if possible, so you'd have to trick the phone into having no connectivity to only one SIM. This isn't possible on the phone.

Comment: The author's SIM does not support WiFi calling.

Comment: They provide no indication of that in their post. Definitely could be the reason (which is why I mentioned that)

Comment: 1. Of course SIM supports wifi calling otherwise this post is illogical. 2. Like I said in my post eSIM's internet works with SIM's wifi calling, but only when I'm in rural areas. I want it to work in city too

Comment: @user3722246 Updated my answer with the new clarifications